# Reverting color change in Jbutton when another Jbutton selected

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

My GUI has a list of filtered entries from a db file. For each entry, I have a select Jbutton which shows more details for each entry.

What I am trying to achieve is to have the select JButton change color when pressed, and revert to original color when another entry's button is selected.

The code I have at the moment will change the selected color's button just fine, but remains the same color when another entry's Details button is selected:

```
//within for loop for each object in database
        JButton selectedButton = new JButton("Details"); 
        selectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                entry.vehicleSelected(); 
                if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton )
                    ((JButton)e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.RED); 
                    ((JButton)e.getSource()).setOpaque(true);
                    ((JButton)e.getSource()).setContentAreaFilled(false);
            }});
```

How can I change the code so I can get this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can introduce a field `JButton buttonToReset` where the last pressed button is saved and use it

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            entry.vehicleSelected(); 
            if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton )
                ((JButton)e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.RED); 
                ((JButton)e.getSource()).setOpaque(true);
                ((JButton)e.getSource()).setContentAreaFilled(false);
                if (buttonToReset!=null) {
                    buttonToReset.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
                }
                buttonToReset = ((JButton)e.getSource());
        }});
```

Comment: This idea is good but I can't get it to work.                                                 JButton buttonToReset = new JButton();

//within for loop for each object in database                                                         
Then the code from your answer...but the buttons still do not reset.

Comment: @Dawson you need to define the variable `buttonToReset` as class member. Also I've simplified the code from StanislavL

Comment: @Sergiy Medvynskyy `buttonToReset.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));` == `buttonToReset.setBackground(null);`

Comment: @mKorbel Why you think so? I've found nothing in swing/awt source code for this behavior (neither in `Component.setBackground` nor in `BasicButtonUI`)

Comment: @Sergiy Medvynskyy both are the same (for JComponents),